# Impossible to have video using kivy on android (Yet another issue using kivy for Android ?)

Tags: kivy, android-videoview, codec, buildozer

Using Kivy
Using buildozer
Using Linux (lubuntu)
Using

PROBLEM : Video appears on linux, not on phone (but sound does)

Extract of python code :

```
import os
os.environ['KIVY_VIDEO'] = 'ffpyplayer'
os.environ['KIVY_AUDIO'] = 'sdl2'
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import VideoPlayer
        self.vid = VideoPlayer(source=vidname, state='play',
                               options={'allow_stretch':False,
                                        'eos': 'loop'})
```

Extract of buildozer file :

```
requirements = python3,kivy,android,ffpyplayer,ffpyplayer_codecs,sdl2,openssl
```

Extract of logs when running (fine) on PC :

```
INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/lefranco/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-10-31_16.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [ImageLoaderFFPy] Using ffpyplayer 4.3.2
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer, img_gif 
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [VideoFFPy   ] Using ffpyplayer 4.3.2
[INFO   ] [Video       ] Provider: ffpyplayer(['video_gstplayer', 'video_ffmpeg'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
```

Versions :

```
Python, Kivy versions : see above 
Linux is lubuntu 20.04
Buildozer is 1.2.0
```

Note : Videos are in different formats, but codec is H.264 MPEG4 (classic I presume)

There seems to be quite an load of such issues with kivy. Making it work for me has proven to be a terrible combat route.

Has someone managed to actually see a video using kivy/android ?

Help and suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I fixed that, but it will probably be useful for others.
I had to change buildozer requirements to kivy==master.
The reason it worked on the pc is that I HAD PREVIOUSLY manually patched the video_ffplayer.py script.
( the patch : I had changed for the time.clock() issue line 240 - time.clock() does not exist in python 3.8 any more and replaced it by time. time() )